# How to add custom mysql column data to WordPress Loop

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to add a custom 'Like' button to a WordPress site.

I have added an extra column to the "wp_posts" table called "post_likes".

What I'm struggling with is if there is any way to output this data as part of the standard WordPress Loop?

My code to retrieve info from DB:

```
function get_articles() {
    $articles = array();

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `ID`, `post_title`, `post_likes` FROM `wp_posts`");
    while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false) {
    $articles[] = array(
        'ID' => $row['ID'],
        'post_title' => $row['post_title'],
        'post_likes' => $row['post_likes']
    );

    }   

    return $articles;
}
```

Current code to output this:

```
 <?php
$articles= get_articles();
foreach ($articles as $article) { echo '<p><a href="#">Like</a> <span>', $article['post_likes'], '</span> Like this</p>'; }
?>
```

But I need to know if there is someway to add this as part of the loop, so I can use thumbnail images, filter by category etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is wrong in SO many ways. **never alter WP tables**.
Your `post_likes` should be a `post_meta` (check [add_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta))

Database connection should be done with [`$wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/wpdb)

And displaying posts should be done in a [Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/the_loop), don't need a DB connection to do this.
In which you could use [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/get_post_meta) to fetch your `post_likes`
And the `like_post` +1 them with [update_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/update_post_meta)

If you need an altered loop use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

**why you should not alter WordPress tables**

1. All alternative 'columns' you need for posts (and users) should be stored in there `*_meta` tables. Take a look at those tables and you should be able to understand how it works.
2. This way you can use all *_post_meta to add/edit/update/delete this data. No need to extra code functions (and make DB calls) yourself
3. If you did made your own columns with functions, caching plugins won't optimize your performance for fetching those parts.
4. if a WP update does something on the database it might delete your data
5. why use Wordpress when you use your own flows and hack/change around WordPress.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply. So essentially I just need to increment post meta every time someone 'Likes' an article. Just out of curiosity, why is it wrong to add to WP tables (obviously not delete / re-name).

Comment: Yeah I'm very much a beginner. I'll try going down the root you suggested with post_meta. Thank you for taking the time for such an informative reply, it's been a big help!

Comment: Good luck, your question in itself was well-structured with clear question and example. It's just your method that is SO wrong. If you have other questions please ask.

Comment: Ok cool, will try working this out & get back with any problems. Thanks again.

Comment: tip too get you started: in the `loop` use `get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'posts_like', true)` to get the current 'likes'